# Android: MenuInflater Works Only On Emulator, Not Real Device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, popup, layout-inflater

For some reason when the following code runs my phone won't display a popup window with the text "+ create new track", yet the same thing works if I run on an Android Studio emulator.

I can't spot the source of this issue. On my emulator `popup.show()` displays a window, but when i step through on my device via a debugger this line does nothing. Strangely, `popup` doesn't seem to be null on the device when this occurs.

How can I get the popup window to display on a real device?

```
private void showTrackListing(){
        int writePermissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (writePermissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Need storage write permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        trackListing = getTrackNames();                      
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), v);

        for (int i = 0; i < trackListing.length; i++) {      //add a menu item for each existing track
            popup.getMenu().add(trackListing[i].getName());
        }

        //TODO: Add Checkable list on longpress to delete files
        //TODO: potentially change popup menu to ListView for better CAB cooperation
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.new_track:
                        trackSelectButton.setText("...");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Name your new track.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        txtTrackName.setVisibility(txtTrackName.VISIBLE);
                        return true;
                    default:
                        selectedTrackName = (item.getTitle().toString());
                        trackSelectButton.setText(selectedTrackName);
                        for (int i = 0; i < trackListing.length; i++) {      //add a menu item for each existing track
                            if (trackListing[i].getName().equals(selectedTrackName)) {
                                selectedTrack = trackListing[i];
                                AudioRecorder.setFile(selectedTrack);
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });

        MenuInflater popupInflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        popupInflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_track_selection, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();
    }
```

*popup_menu_track_selection.xml*

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <item android:id="@+id/new_track"
            android:title="+ create new track"/>
    </menu>
```

Comment: post your "popup_menu_track_selection" layout

Comment: @RajeshPanchal added.

Comment: did u add `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` ?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 Yes, I have. The permissions don't seem to be directly related to the issue of the popup not showing.